# How do I declare index=0 in .h file iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, declare

```
// Declare index in Header.h

index=0;

- (IBAction)next {
    index++;
    // Set imageCount to as many images as are available
    int imageCount=2;
    if (index<=imageCount) {
        NSString* imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%i", index];
        [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]];
    }
}
```

Where do I declare index in my header file and how?

Comment: I get an error index redeclared as a different kind of symbol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `index` is used only within the `-next` method, you can define a static variable.

```
- (IBAction)next {
    static int index = 0;    // <-- here
    index++;
    // Set imageCount to as many images as are available
    int imageCount=2;
    if (index<=imageCount) {
        NSString* imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"img%i", index];
        [picture setImage: [UIImage imageNamed: imageName]];
    }
}
```

Note that all instances will share the same `index`.

But I believe it's better to make `index` as an ivar, e.g.

```
@interface ... {
   ...
   int index;
   ...
}
```

it is automatically initialized to 0 when the instance is constructed, and methods other than `next` can use the `index`. Also, each instance will have its own `index`.

Comment: Ok the only problem I now have is that all my images (16) are called img01 img02 etc but none of my images are now displaying except first one how does this work?

Comment: Ok now when I click next no image is displayed?

Comment: @Will: You need `img%02d` instead of `img%i`.

Comment: Wait I have changed all of my images to img1 img2 and so on but it still won't display them except for the first one when I click next where the image should be just goes white :(

Comment: @Will: Which iPhone OS version are you running on? You need the file extension i.e. `img%i.png` if you're targeting iPhone OS <4.